# PIC24H delta time calculation

Tags: pic, c, timer, microprocessor

Hello I'm making a project for my intro embedded software class and I need to make use of a timer in a program.  If I'm not mistaken this code should be looping the while for at least 500 milliseconds, but it's not working and I've never done this before on a PIC!  There may be an issue with the data types in the calculation for ms conversion.

Help would be amazing!

```
#define CLOCKS_PER_SEC 8000000  //Clock set to 8MHz
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (void)
{
    //Used to keep track of timer
    unsigned long delta_time, init_time, final_time;

    init_time=clock();  //Take initial clock reading
    delta_t=0;
    while(delta_t < 500)
    {

        //do tasks


        final_time=clock();    // returns total number of clocks
        delta_t= final - initial;  //Calculates total clocks between final and initial

        // converts to ms
        delta_t = (unsigned long)((delta_t/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC*1.0))*1000;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you're declaring `delta_t` anywhere. This is also true for `final` and `initial` (`delta_t= final - initial;`). I would imagine that `final` is really `final_time`, and `initial` is really `init_time`, but why are you asking a question about code that isn't from your actual project?

Please post code that actually compiles.

---

On `delta_t = (unsigned long)((delta_t/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC*1.0))*1000;`

Why are you converting to a float, and then back? You don't need to. 
Instead, divide `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` down so it's `CLOCKS_PER_MILLISEC`. Then you can do everything with ints:
`delta_ms = (delta_clocks/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000));`

This needs no type-conversion, and will be MUCH faster.

<sup>Note: I've renamed some of your variables for better understandability.</sup>

Comment: WOW I fixed the calculation and it seems to have solved my issue.  Yeah I just started casting everything when it wasn't working haha.  I got a little confused!  Thanks again!

Comment: @user2256010 - If the different time calculation solved your problem, please accept this answer. Click the check-mark below this post's vote count.